# Geometric series in a probability question

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

When $A$ and $B$ flip coins, the one coming closest to a given line wins $1$ penny from the other. If $A$ starts with $3$ and $B$ with $7$ pennies, what is the probability that $A$ winds up with all of the money if both players are equally skilled?
What if A were a better player who won $60\%$ percent of the time?

This question I found in the end of the Sheldon Ross introduction (3rd chapter) to probability book. The given answer is $0.3$ but I am not sure for which question exactly, however neither of my answers is equal to that and I am not sure how to exactly apply the basic terms of probility "events" to this type of questions.

My attempt:

first question -
$$ P(A)=P(B)=\frac{1}{2}$$
$$ P(A \,wins \,all) := 0 \,losses : AAAAAAA$$
$$ 1\, loss :BAAAAAAAA, ABAAA.....  $$
$$ 2\, loss :....$$

## and so on , which can be formulated by:

$$ P(A)= \frac{1}{2^7}*\sum_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{2n}}= \frac{1}{2^7}*\frac{4}{3}=0.01$$
Now, I am not sure if I should consider that if A losses 3 matches in a row in the beginning it basically loses I guess?

Second question, I used a similar method:
$$ 0.6^7*\sum_{0}^{\infty} 0.6^n*0.4^n= 0.6^7*\frac{1}{1-\frac{6}{25}} = 0.037  $$

Any hints, or advice greatly appreciated!

Comment: What does "closest to a line" mean? What is a win in this question?

Comment: @Vizag - Just imagine that each round each player has a $50\%$ chance of winning (or later $60\% : 40\%$)

Comment: This is still unclear to me... Rephrased, are you saying that $A$ starts with "3 points" and $B$ starts with "7 points."  Each turn $A$ and $B$ play a game where each has probability $\frac{1}{2}$ of winning and they cannot tie, each game's outcome is independent, the winner of the game gains a point while the loser loses a point, and they continue this cycle of playing games until there is a player who reaches 10 points and is declared the overall winner while the other player reaches zero points and is declared the overall loser?

Comment: @JMoravitz I think that is what it is. Any person that gets all the points, wins.

Comment: Truth is I copied it exactly as it is written, so I have problem understanding the problem myself. I believe the closest to the line can indicate a tie is possible, but I am not sure how could that be implemented in this case, or if it is really needed.

Comment: So... your probabilities you calculated seem to be following the idea that if $A$ wins, then he must win seven games in a row after there being some "back and forth" with the score for a while.  The probability you *actually* calculated is where $A$ wins, then $B$ wins, then $A$ wins, then $B$ wins, back and forth always $A$ followed by $B$ any number of times followed by seven consecutive wins for $A$.  Of course, there are many more arrangements of wins and losses that result in an overall win for $A$, not just these.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $1\le n\le 9$, let $p_n$ be the probability that $A$ wins if $A$ has $n$ pennies before starting the next round.

Then we have the following system of $5$ equations in $5$ unknowns . . .

\begin{cases}
p_1=\frac{1}{2}p_2\\[4pt]
p_2=\frac{1}{2}p_3+\frac{1}{2}p_1\\[4pt]
p_3=\frac{1}{2}p_4+\frac{1}{2}p_2\\[4pt]
p_4=\frac{1}{2}p_5+\frac{1}{2}p_3\\[4pt]
p_5=\frac{1}{2}\;\;\;\text{[by symmetry]}\\
\end{cases}
Solving the system yields $p_3=\frac{3}{10}$

If instead of equal skills, we assume that $A$ has probability $\frac{3}{5}$ of winning each round, we get the following system of $9$ equations in $9$ unknowns . . .
\begin{cases}
p_1=\frac{3}{5}p_2
\qquad\qquad\qquad\;\;
\\[4pt]
p_2=\frac{3}{5}p_3+\frac{2}{5}p_1\\[4pt]
p_3=\frac{3}{5}p_4+\frac{2}{5}p_2\\[4pt]
p_4=\frac{3}{5}p_5+\frac{2}{5}p_3\\[4pt]
p_5=\frac{3}{5}p_6+\frac{2}{5}p_4\\[4pt]
p_6=\frac{3}{5}p_7+\frac{2}{5}p_5\\[4pt]
p_7=\frac{3}{5}p_8+\frac{2}{5}p_6\\[4pt]
p_8=\frac{3}{5}p_9+\frac{2}{5}p_7\\[4pt]
p_9=\frac{3}{5}+\frac{2}{5}p_8
\end{cases}
Solving the system yields $p_3={\large{\frac{41553}{58025}}}\approx 0.7161223611$

Comment: That $p_5 = 0.5$ didn't click to me and I was solving the whole bunch of equations. Neat (+1)

Comment: However tho, if $p \neq 0.5$, then one needs to go about solving i think $10$ equations. The assumption $p_5=0.5$ won't hold there.

Comment: Yes, but the system can be solved easily, eliminating one variable at a time.

Comment: Yes you're right. It can be solved by elimination. I was merely pointing it out for the OP.

Comment: Oh, I didn't look carefully -- I thought you were the OP.